# Membership contribution with profile required 'on behalf of' prefilled

Tags: civicrm

I'm helping a nonprofit with a Drupal/CiviCRM site. They track memberships in CiviCRM which are associated with an organization as the primary member, and individuals linked to the organization by relationships to share this membership.

Using the "CiviMember Roles Sync" module, these individuals are granted access to a member role in Drupal.

I've created a contribution page in CiviCRM for membership signup or renewal, and since the primary member is actually the organization, I've checked "Allow individuals to contribute and/or signup for membership on behalf of an organization". Since it is a requirement, I've also made this required instead of optional. (Screenshot below).

[image]

The help text here indicates that "logged in users will be given a choice of selecting from a list of organizations that they have a permissioned relationship with OR entering a new organization" -- however, I am not able to produce the select/list despite assigning "view and update information" permissions in both directions on the relationship between the individual and the organization. The contribution page just allows typing in a text field for the org name, which will produce a lot of duplicates and extra work.

Am I missing a step to get the select list which will prefill the org's information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour that you are expecting to see will work - at least it does for me - when the relationship between the individual and the organisation is "Employee of". Other relationship types appear not to work. Perhaps you are using a different relationship type?

Comment: This should be clarified in the on-screen help text, and perhaps questioned. I can see many use cases where other relationship types should be able to sign up or renew a membership for an organisation they are involved with.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Yes, they are using different relationship types here. Do you have any idea where in the code this Employee relationship is hard-coded? I wonder if I could attempt a modification and submit a pull request to fix this. Or is there a process I should go through first to make sure the core team agrees?

Comment: @Laryn I'm on the core team and I agree :)

Comment: @Coleman, see what you think of this approach: http://github.com/laryn/civicrm-core/compare/patch-1

It's not perfect yet, there is some strange behaviour when there is one non-employee relationship where the name doesn't show (it works if there are two permissioned relationships) but it's a start. Where do you recommend I move this conversation -- forums?

Comment: @Laryn can you create an issue at [issues.civicrm.org](http://issues.civicrm.org) for this? We can continue work there.

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15596